# Sequelize: Typescript throws an error after attempting to compile an empty 'user.model.ts' file

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

Looking for help;
It's a weird issue. I'm starting my first TS app, using `sequelize-typescript` and `sequelize` as my ORMs.
Managed to setup my app, server and connection with the database, but something very weird is happening after I create a model file.
My typescript compiler is in a watch mode, command used is `ts-node-esm ./src/server.ts`.
Right after I create ANY file in path `./src/models/` (the problem dissapears if I rename the folder to anything else than 'models', compiler does not see any issue) the compiler throws an error:

`G:\OneDrive\CODING\js\TweetSphere\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-errors.js:46 const err = new Error(getErrRequireEsmMessage(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath)) ^ Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: G:\OneDrive\CODING\js\TweetSphere\src\models\tweet.model.ts require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of G:\OneDrive\CODING\js\TweetSphere\src\models\tweet.model.ts from G:\OneDrive\CODING\js\TweetSphere\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize-service.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from G:\OneDrive\CODING\js\TweetSphere\package.json.`

The problem is, my entire project has ES6 modules and all the imports are done in `import {function} from 'package'` which is the reason this confuses me.

My whole research resulted in me looking for any accidental CJS imports, but I couldn't find any.
Also:
My package.json does include "type": "module"
My tsconfig.json includes lines:
`

```
"target": "ES6",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"module": "NodeNext",
"rootDir": "./src",
"moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "./dist",
"removeComments": true,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I digged even deeper, apparently the sequelize package does not support Node 13+
That explains the issue

Comment: Not correct, check [this](https://sequelize.org/releases/). The error seems to be stemming from the `tweet` model, and if you're using the `user` model inside of it, while creating an empty file, consider importing something in the file, or exporting something from it, that'll make it a module, otherwise it's not considered as a module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).